# How do you animate to expand a container from 0 height to the height of its contents in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-container

I have a container that starts at zero height and needs to be expanded after a user interaction.

- I tried using AnimatedContainer / AnimatedSize and changing the child widget's height from `0` to `null`, but in both cases, Flutter complains that it cant' interpolate from `0` to `null`.
- I've also tried using BoxConstraints (with expanded using `maxHeight = double.infinity`) instead of explicit heights, in which case Flutter complains it can't interpolate from a finite value to an indefinite one.
- I've also tried setting mainAxisSize to min/max, in which case Flutter complains that `vsync` is `null`.

How do I animate expanding a widget such that it dynamically grows big enough to wrap its contents? And if this can't be done dynamically, what's a safe way to size contents such that they make sense across screen sizes? In web dev, I know things like `em` are sort of relative sizing, but in the context of Flutter, I don't see how to control the size of things reliably.

---

Update: As suggested by @pskink, wrapping the child in an Align widget and animating Align's heightFactor param accomplishes collapsing. However, I'm still having trouble getting collapse to work when the collapsing child itself has children. For example, Column widgets don't clip at all with ClipRect (see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29357), and even if I use Wrap instead of Column, that doesn't work if the Wrap's children are Rows. Not sure how to get clipping to work consistently.

Comment: check `expansion_tile.dart` source file - it uses `Align.heightFactor` that makes a trick

Comment: @pskink it sort of works, but it's not clipping even with a ClipRect wrapping it. How do you make it clip?

Comment: @pskink ClipRect doesn't work on a column/wrap/row

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by that

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29357 I mean it doesn't clip columns/wraps/rows

Comment: @pskink ah it looks like it does work for Wraps. I guess I'll switch to a Wrap :( kind of frustrating that columns don't clip though

Comment: updated question to reflect new findings. Still can't get it to work consistently with clipping

Comment: @pskink moved summary of this to an answer below. Thank you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Maybe you could also solve this with a [SizeTransition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizeTransition-class.html)?

[image]

```
class VariableSizeContainerExample extends StatefulWidget {
  VariableSizeContainerExample();

  @override
  _VariableSizeContainerExampleState createState() => _VariableSizeContainerExampleState();
}

class _VariableSizeContainerExampleState extends State<VariableSizeContainerExample> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
    );
  }

  _toggleContainer() {
    print(_animation.status);
    if (_animation.status != AnimationStatus.completed) {
      _controller.forward();
    } else {
      _controller.animateBack(0, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => _toggleContainer(),
                child: Text("Toggle container visibility"),
              ),
              SizeTransition(
                sizeFactor: _animation,
                axis: Axis.vertical,
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    "This can have variable size",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text("This is below the above container"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked great! @pskink's answer works too, but required a bit more wiring. This one does exactly what I want in a straightforward way. I want to also mention that if anyone wants it to collapse from the bottom (as opposed to toward the middle), you can add `axisAlignment: -1` to the SizeTransition params

Comment: Is there a way so it doesn't go all the way to 0 when it gets smaller? In my case the trigger is the content itself and if they click on it it either grows in size to show the full content or folds itself until it reaches a height of 50. This way the user has space to click on it again to make it expand.

Comment: @enchance I just did some (minimal) testing on your behalf. You can't use _controller.animateBack(0.5, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), to accomplish this. You have to use "animateTo" to get to a certain position. Perhaps you could add an extra variable to control having one click make the Widget 50 percent size, and a second click will fully close, where the last click will use "animateBack()". You can also set the size scale manually by setting _controller.value = 0.5, but that would rebuild the widget if you did it in setState, making it "snap" to 50 percent size (looks bad).

Comment: I did end up testing this, and made it work with a simple int counter var. In the first setState -> animateTo(1), second call to setState() -> animateTo(0.5), and last call to setState() -> animateBack(0). I didn't add the counter incrementing in this comment, but I believe in you! ~Very Best.

Answer (score 3):

Moving @pskink's comments to an answer for posterity:

The main concept is that the [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget has a property called `heightFactor`, which takes a double between 0 and 1 to scale its child's height (there's also a similar `widthFactor` property for width). By animating this property, we can collapse/expand the child. For example:

```
ClipRect(
      child: Align(
        alignment: alignment,
        child: Align(
          alignment: innerAlignment,
          widthFactor: constantValue,
          heightFactor: animatedValue.value,
          child: builder(context, animation),
        ),
      )
)
```

where `animatedValue` is of type `Animation<double>`, and `ClipReact` is used to clip/truncate the child widget. Note that `ClipReact` needs to be wrapped *outside* the `Align` widget; it doesn't work consistently when wrapping `Align`'s child widget.

Edit: it's also necessary for the recipient of the animation to be an AnimatedWidget for things to go smoothly. See selected answer for an approach that handles this for you.

Comment: Using this with TweenAnimationBuilder was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@kohjakob's answer worked, but it isn't a reusable widget.

So I made `AnimatedCollapse`. It is based on the style of the other `Animated[...]` widgets, and it uses the `SizeTransition` and listens for any changes in the `collapsed` property to reverse or forward the animation.

```
class AnimatedCollapse extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedCollapse({
    Key? key,
    this.child,
    required this.collapsed,
    this.axis = Axis.vertical,
    this.axisAlignment = 0.0,
    this.curve = Curves.linear,
    required this.duration,
    this.reverseDuration,
  }) : super(key: key);


  final Widget? child;

  /// Show or hide the child
  final bool collapsed;

  /// See [SizeTransition]
  final Axis axis;

  /// See [SizeTransition]
  final double axisAlignment;
  final Curve curve;
  final Duration duration;
  final Duration? reverseDuration;

  @override
  _AnimatedCollapseState createState() => _AnimatedCollapseState();
}

class _AnimatedCollapseState extends State<AnimatedCollapse> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: widget.duration,
      reverseDuration: widget.reverseDuration,
    );

    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: widget.curve,
    );

    if (!widget.collapsed) {
      _controller.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant AnimatedCollapse oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (widget.collapsed != oldWidget.collapsed) {
      if (widget.collapsed) {
        _controller.reverse();
      } else {
        _controller.forward();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: _animation,
      axis: widget.axis,
      axisAlignment: widget.axisAlignment,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you would like the animation not to play when the widget loads for the first time, add `initialValue: 1` to the AnimationController

Comment: In `initState`, add `value: widget.collapsed ? 0.0 : 1.0,` to the `AnimationController`, and remove the call to `_controller.forward()`. This will make it so the widget is either fully extended or fully collapsed on build. Otherwise a widget that isn't collapsed will do it's whole "reveal" animation on build, instead of only on state change.